# Biztalk Mapper Inline XSLT Call Template Email Validation

Tags: xslt, biztalk, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-mapper

I'm trying to validate an email address via a map to confirm to the validation rule `\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)`.
I'm new to this and haven't found much help via search, so will post the in-line xslt call I have to see if someone can correct my mistake.

```
<xsl:template name="EmailAdress" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" >
 <xsl:param name="inEmail"/>
 <xsl:element name="p:Email" >
     <xsl:value-of select="Maches(upper-case(inEmail),'\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)'/>
 </xsl:element>
```

Comment: The "matches" and "upper-case" functions are XSLT 2.0 functions. Does BizTalk mapper support that?

Comment: @TimC you are correct, these are unsupported by the version of Biztalk were currently implementing.  An alternative solution had to be sort :).

Answer (score 1):

This was handled by implementing two script functoids (one inline xslt Call Template, the other Inline C#) with the following code execution:

One

```
<xsl:template name="eaddress">
  <xsl:param name="memail"/>
  <xsl:if test="userCSharp:valEmailAdd(.)">
    <email><xsl:value-of select="."/><email>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Two

```
public bool valEmailAdd(string eadd) {return regex.match(eadd, @"<validation>").Success;}
```